# Number of semistandard Young Tableaux

Tags: combinatorics

(this is straight from the wiki for Schur polynomials)

For a partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1, ... ,\lambda_n)$, the Schur polynomial is a sum of monomials $$S_\lambda(x_1,x_2,...x_n) = \sum_T X^T$$

Where the Sum is taken over all semistandard Young Tableaux of shape $\lambda$

What I would like is an upper bound on the number of terms in this polynomial.

Comment: See the second comment on OEIS sequence [A209673](https://oeis.org/A209673). This at least gives you data to check against...

Comment: Thanks that helps give me some data, it seems like a pretty trivial bound would be $a(n) \le n^n$ but I have no idea how I would prove this

Comment: I'm guessing when you asked that the bound depend on $n$ that you meant _only_ on $n$, since any bound based on $\lambda$ is implicitly based on $n$, and because you proposed $n^n$ as a possible bound.  As my answer shows, such a bound does not exist, but if I misunderstood you (and you're asking for a bound that depends on $\lambda$), let me know and I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: After looking at some of the literature linked to by the OEIS page, I see that Young Tableauxs (both standard and semi-standard) are usually characterized by the number of "boxes", not the number of rows, as you do.  Is this what you intended? Asking for a bound on the number of Ferrer's diagrams (let alone Tableauxs) with $n$ rows is equivalent to asking for a bound on the number of numbers which can be expressed as the sum of $n$ natural numbers, which is clearly boundless.

Comment: Strike that. It's equivalent to asking for a bound on the number of $n$-elment multisets of natural numbers.  Still, in either case you're talking about a countably infinite set.